# I have an image of a map, I want to divide it into four squares and find the top left and bottom right coords of each piece

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, coordinates, mapping, imagery

I have attempted this before using lat, long finder websites, however as they use a different map projection to mine (which is equarectangular) the coords are always a little bit off. Now, I can split the map into exactly four square pieces using an online tool but I need some way to overlay those pieces over an equarectangular QGIS to find the coordinates of each corner, is this doable?

Edit: By the map I mean a png image of a map of the uk. The online tool is where you click on a map (supplied by the website) to get lat,long coords, nothing to do with my image. Here is the online tool: https://www.latlong.net/ I wish to use my image overlayed over a map in qgis instead of this online tool to find the precise coordinates.

Comment: What do you mean by **the map**? What are you inputting in the online tool?

Comment: @BERA clarification made in edit.

Comment: You can georeference your map in QGIS, than you can click anywhere on your warped map to see coordinates. In newer QGIS versions: Menu Layer > Georefrencer; in older versions: Menu Vector > Georeferenceer

Comment: @Babel I’ll give it a go and if I can get it qorking i’ll make this post as answered!